# Use the contents of a Text Box to justify a URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, textbox

How to use a text box contents to justify the URL. For example, if I would like people to go to `www.url.com/id1`, then they should enter `id1` into the textbox. I don't want it to be `www.url.com?id=1`.

Comment: what do you mean "justify a url"?

Comment: @BrianFitzGerald I mean, for example, if you were to type email in a box for google, it would go to google.com/email or if you typed documents, it would go to google.com/documents

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
<script>
  function searchKeyPress(e) {
      // Enter was pressed
      e = e || window.event;
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          window.location = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
</script>

<input type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event);" />
```